# update field using a subquery with left join and group_concat from another table

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I'm using the next code, but it fails and I don't know why.

```
UPDATE pd
SET pd.meta_categories = x.categories
FROM t_product_description pd
JOIN (
    SELECT p.product_id AS productid, GROUP_CONCAT(cd.name SEPARATOR ' ') AS categories
    FROM t_product AS p
    LEFT JOIN t_product_to_category AS p2c ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)
    LEFT JOIN t_category_description AS cd ON (cd.category_id = p2c.category_id)
    GROUP BY p.product_id
) x ON pd.product_id = x.productid
```

Comment: what do you mean with "but it fails"  .. you have an error ? then show the error message .   you have wrong result? the show a data sample the expected  resutl and your actula result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in mysql the join clause became first, (don't need  from ) and the the set clause  and

```
UPDATE t_product_description pd
JOIN (
    SELECT p.product_id AS productid, GROUP_CONCAT(cd.name SEPARATOR ' ') AS categories
    FROM t_product AS p
    LEFT JOIN t_product_to_category AS p2c ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)
    LEFT JOIN t_category_description AS cd ON (cd.category_id = p2c.category_id)
    GROUP BY p.product_id
) x ON pd.product_id = x.productid
SET pd.meta_categories = x.categories
```